# Durandal modal dialog position issue when content added after initial display

Tags: durandal

I display a modal dialog with a small "please wait" message whilst an Ajax request is underway. Once that request is finished, the result is injected into the content of the modal dialog. If it is significantly larger, obviously the size calculations are thrown off and the "OK" button disappears off the bottom of the screen, requiring a reload to clear the modal!

Is there anything that can be done to resize/reposition the modal dialog after I inject the new content into it, or do I need to change my logic to show a "please wait" and then close it and display the new modal dialog in its completed state?

Comment: Is the new content obtained _within_ the dialog context, or external to the dialog context?  I take it that it's not the "Please Wait" dialog context making the AJAX call. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not within. I create a new modal object and "show" it, then using the object reference, push in the content when the ajax call is completed.

Comment: I responded with an answer.  Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to take over the repositioning logic of a Durandal dialog, you would create a custom dialog context.  Place your repositioning logic inside of the `compositionComplete` handler.

Resize, on the other hand, can be handled strictly with CSS.  But it can be handled in the `compositionComplete` handler of the custom dialog context as well.

We have written several custom dialog contexts, and use the approach above to achieve what you are trying to achieve.  We have even gone so far as to include special animations in the `compositionComplete` handler.

Take a look [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html) in Durandal's documentation.

Also, I have uploaded to my public OneDrive a short movie of one of our custom dialog contexts. You can view it [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=16C2A8798026D00B!178&authkey=!ABf6gbPiPpRcLfI&ithint=video,.mp4). The slide-out window that pops in front is actually a custom Durandal dialog context.

Comment: That's very cool! :-)  I'll read up on it a bit more and come back to you if I have any problems understanding, thanks. Rob Eisenberg has told me that Durandal 2.1.0 (released soon) has a "reposition" method on the dialog context.

Answer (score 0):

In Durandal 2.1.0, there will be a method to to reposition the dialog. See:

https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/Version-2.1.0/docs/2.x/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html.md#repositioning-dialogs-after-their-contents-have-been-changed